# Setting textLabel.text in UITableView using JSON data

Tags: ios5

I will preface the question with I am new to iOS and could use a little push. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days and fear I am not able to figure out the solution out of my frustration. It is my hope that some new eyes backed with experience will be able to help me out with this.

I have a JSON file that I want to use for various portions of my application. The file can be viewed at https://raw.github.com/irong8/stronger-nation-data/master/data.json for reference.

I am using Storyboards and want to accomplish this using the built in JSON support of iOS5. I created a new TableViewController subclass and have included the code below.

**Here is my .h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface StateTableViewController : UITableViewController
{
    NSArray *StateList;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *StateList;

- (void) buildStateList;

@end
```

**Here is my .m file**

```
#import "StateTableViewController.h"

@implementation StateTableViewController

@synthesize StateList;

- (void)buildStateList {
    NSString *jsonFile = [ [NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"json" ];
    NSError *jsonError = nil;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonFile options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError ];
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonError];

    NSArray *jsonArray = [json objectForKey:@"states"];

    self.StateList = jsonArray;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self buildStateList];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [StateList count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

I can loop through the StateList array using the following and see the state names I am looking for.

```
for (NSString *element in StateList) {
    NSLog(@"element: %@", element);
}
```

When I load this view, a TableView is loaded with 50 rows (as expected as there are 50 state records in my data file) and each row is numbered 0-49. I am having trouble figuring out how to access the state name in my StateList array.

Any help along the way would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would populate your tableview's cells with data in `cellForRow..`. Here is a slight modification of the default implementation in new projects:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    NSInteger rowNumber = indexPath.row;
    NSString *stateName = [StateList objectAtIndex:rowNumber];
    cell.textLabel.text = stateName;
    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT** The reason your app is now crashing is the object for the key `"states"` is a dictionary (as it should be according to the `json` at the link you posted) and you cannot simply cast it to an array. You can, however, ask the dictionary for an array of all of the keys. Which in this case will be the state names.

Change this line of code in `buildStateList`:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [[json objectForKey:@"states"] allKeys];
```

Comment: I replaced my implementation with the one you provided and I received this error message: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a07090". I have cast my StateList array of type NSArray so I am not sure what the dictionary item is or where that would be coming from.

Comment: Edited in response to comment.

Comment: you sir are a scholar and a gentlemen! That worked perfectly. Seeing your implementation changes has allowed me to have a greater understanding of the issue I had and why what I had was not working.